# Canvas arc() vs drawImage()

Tags: performance, html5-canvas

This may seem innocuous, but when doing it 1000+ times at 30 frames per second, it does add up. I have 3 sizes of circles that I draw, each with their own fill color (RGBA). Is it faster for me to draw them as images once, and use `drawImage()` with the data URLs, or to do `arc()` for each of them?

Extra information:

- Using a single canvas for all circles
- Context and canvas are cached
- Full call for arc at the moment looks like

  this.scene.context.arc(newLocation, this.y+=this.speed/80, this.distance / 2, 0, Math.PI*2, false);

Comment: If you already have your code, you can check which version is faster at [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: If you end up using the arc() method you can optimise that line. eg set the context as a local variable if in a function, or just as a variable so that "this" and "scene" don't have to be looked up as well and do the calculations once. Eg var TWOPI = Math.PI * 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

According to [my tests](http://jsperf.com/canvas-arc-vs-drawimage), `drawImage()` is going to be significantly faster in most cases than using `arc()`.

The `drawImage()` function can take either an `<img>` or `<canvas>` element as its parameter, and in Firefox, using an `<img>` tag was faster, though other browsers showed the opposite.

What it boils down to: Even for simple shapes, use `drawImage()`

Answer (score 1):

`drawImage()` is faster, but only in Firefox.

There's a trick that gives the same performance in Chrome as `drawImage()` gives in Firefox:

```js
const drawCircle = function(ctx, x, y, radius) {
  ctx.lineWidth = radius * 2;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

In Chrome 84, this method using round line caps is about 3x faster than anything else:

[image: Bar graph showing a performance comparison between Chrome and Firefox]

Interestingly, Firefox 79 is the exact opposite: that trick turns out to be the slowest option, with arc being only a bit faster.

The tests I used are [here](https://jsperf.com/canvas-arc-vs-drawimage/24).